# Raspberry Chromium kiosk Foyer ("Aw, Snap")

Tags: chromium, kiosk

We are running Raspberry 4b and 3b as Kiosk TV. We have around 150 working system over the country. We are ''streaming'' with help of Wordpress plugin Foyer.

Chromium version is latest, Chrome/88.0.4324.187, running fine, without any problems.

Previous week we had first issue, at only one place (In this place are running cca. 15 Raspberries). We had issue of displaying simple image (1920x1080). There is no error in log file, or something that would help us diagnose problem.

We get error code 11 (image is attached).

[image]

And from command "dmesg" we get: [image]

Does anyone experienced the same problem? We are limited, because we can only control systems remotely.

I'm also attaching openChromium script, that starts Chromium at startup.

```
chromium-browser %U --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS armv7l 12371.89.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.187 Safari/537.36" \
  --enable-logging=stderr --v=1 > log.txt 2>&1 --noerrdialogs \
  --disable-infobars --disable-translate --no-first-run --fast \
  --fast-start --incognito --enable-features=OverlayScrollbar \
  --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' \
  --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required \
  --start-maximized --kiosk
```

Thanks in advance.